# why the ideal $(f)$ is prime for $n >1$ ? Atiyah book

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have some confusion in Atiyah commutative algebra Page No :$4$

> $A$ ring with only a finite number of maximal ideals is called semi-local

> Example :$A = k[x_1, ... , x_n]$, $k$ a field. Let $f \in A$ be an irreducible polynomial.

> By unique factorization, the ideal $(f)$ is prime.

**My question** : Im not getting why  the ideal $(f)$ is prime for $n >1$ ?

My thinking  : Suppose for $n=1 $. Then $A=k[x_1]$ and  ideal generated by $(x_1)=(f)$  is maximal because it is  principal.This implies the ideal $(f)$ is prime  because every maximal is prime

$$\frac{k[x_1]}{(f)} \cong  k$$

Now ,Suppose $n=3$,then $A=k[x_1,x_2,x_3]$.

By the theorem if $k $ is field then $k[x]$ is field. Also, by induction $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n] $ is UFD

Now the ideal generated by $(x_1,x_2 ,x_3)=(f)$  is not maximal because it is not principal.

This implies $(f)$ is not  a prime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ideal $I$ is prime if $ab\in I$ implies $a\in I$ or $b\in I$.  So if you take two polynomials $g,h$ and say $gh\in (f)$, that means there is a polynomial $k$ such that $gh=fk$.  Since $f$ is irreducible, we must have $f|g$ or $f|h$ (Same logic as for prime numbers).